# Zabbix file system autodiscovery does not kick in

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I have the following set up

- Zabbix server 2.2.2
- Zabbix agent 2.2.2

I have the agent running on several Ubuntu 14.04 servers which have Template Linux OS applied on them. For some reason, the file system autodiscovery (free space on partition, etc.) items do not appear in the host item list. There is no indication in log files, both agent and server, what could go wrong. The file systems still appear on some older hosts I added to Zabbix earlier, long time ago.

Do I need to take some actions in Zabbix server GUI in order to make file-system discovery happen (I thought this was automatic)? Is there something else that could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the template, discovery runs only once an hour. So you need to wait a bit after you add a new host before this data becomes available.

[image: Zabbix Template OS Linux discovery rules]